# Copy/pasting query in Google Sheets between cells with automatic replacement of values

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, limit, google-query-language

I have this query in my sheet:
`=query(A2:A100, "Order by A Desc Limit 20")`

I want to copy and paste it to more cells and expect it will update range and column from A2:A100 to B2:B100, C2:C100 etc.. and A in query to B, C etc.

`=query(B2:B100, "Order by B Desc Limit 20")`

`=query(C2:C100, "Order by C Desc Limit 20")`

But when I copy/paste, it only updates range, but not query.
How to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=SORTN(A2:A100; 20; 1; 1; 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this instead for copy-pasting w/no issues:

```
=query({A2:A100}, "Order by Col1 Desc Limit 20")
```